# overloading the print_node(pNode) function in xmlpp::DomParser

Tags: c++, autotools

I'm using the DomParser in C++ on Debian 10.5 made available by `libxml++-2.6` API to extract data from XML files. To work with the extracted data, I call functions I've embedded between nodes, that store the data to vectors and maps, for convenient retrieval when I need it to populate templates in my application. The functions are made available by overloading the `print_node` function with a class object. This works perfectly well when I compile and run the code within the Debian Environment as it sees the overloaded function. The problem arises when I use the Autotools: Automake does not see the
overloaded function. And this is where I am at my wits end in what to do.

**Here are snapshot of my code to help you better understand what my problem is.
The following piece of code calls the libxml++-2.6 API through the function
`runConxsParser(conxs, itr->relative_path().string());`**

```
#include "config.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include "xml_structs.h"
#include "debug.h"
#include "conxsTracker.cpp"
#include "xmlConxsParser.cpp"


namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

using namespace std;

vector<FncBlkPath> appFuncBlcks;


vector<fs::path> get_all(fs::path const & root, std::string const & ext)
{

  vector<fs::path> paths;
  if (fs::exists(root) && fs::is_directory(root))
  {   

    for (auto const & entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(root))
    {
      if (fs::is_regular_file(entry) && entry.path().extension() == ext)
      { 
        cout << entry.path() << endl;
        paths.emplace_back(entry);
      }
    }
  }

  return paths;
}
void displayappFuncBlcks()
{
    cout << "Display appFuncBlcks vec content "  << endl;
    for(vector<FncBlkPath>::iterator itr = appFuncBlcks.begin(), 
                end = appFuncBlcks.end();  itr != end; ++itr)
    {
      cout << itr->typeName  << endl;
      cout << itr->filePath  << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
  /** Interates through the current system diagram project for find all function block types
      Adds them to a the vector appFuncBlcks.
  
      */
  CONXS conxs;

  struct FncBlkPath fbFilePath;
  //struct System conxsFilePath

  fs::path p{"./src/oven_control"};

  vector<fs::path> fbpaths = get_all(p, ".fbt");
  
  for(vector<fs::path>::iterator itr = fbpaths.begin(), 
                end = fbpaths.end();  itr != end; ++itr)
  {

    fbFilePath.typeName = itr->stem().string();
    //fbFilePath.filePath = itr->parent_path().string();
    fbFilePath.filePath = itr->relative_path().string();
    appFuncBlcks.push_back(fbFilePath);
  }
  
  vector<fs::path> syspath = get_all(p, ".sys");

  for(vector<fs::path>::iterator itr = syspath.begin(), 
                end = syspath.end();  itr != end; ++itr)
  {


    //conxs.setSystemOrSubApp(itr->stem().string())

    if(DEBUG)
      cout << "System Path " << itr->relative_path().string() << endl;
    runConxsParser(conxs, itr->relative_path().string());
  } 
  

  if (DEBUG)
    displayappFuncBlcks();
return 0;
}
```

This piece of code shows the functions i use in the libxml++-2.6 API to store the extracted data

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif

#include <libxml++/libxml++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void conxs_print_indentation(unsigned int indentation)
{
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < indentation; ++i)
    std::cout << " ";
}

//int myCount = 0;

void print_node(const xmlpp::Node* node, CONXS &conxs, unsigned int indentation = 0)
{


  std::cout << std::endl; //Separate nodes by an empty line.

  const xmlpp::ContentNode* nodeContent = dynamic_cast<const xmlpp::ContentNode*>(node);
  const xmlpp::TextNode* nodeText = dynamic_cast<const xmlpp::TextNode*>(node);
  const xmlpp::CommentNode* nodeComment = dynamic_cast<const xmlpp::CommentNode*>(node);

  if(nodeText && nodeText->is_white_space()) //Let's ignore the indenting - you don't always want to do this.
    return;


  Glib::ustring nodename = node->get_name();


  if(!nodeText && !nodeComment && !nodename.empty()) //Let's not say "name: text".
  {
    conxs_print_indentation(indentation);
    std::cout << "Node name = " << node->get_name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Node name = " << nodename << std::endl;
  }
  else if(nodeText) //Let's say when it's text. - e.g. let's say what that white space is.
  {
    conxs_print_indentation(indentation);
    std::cout << "Text Node" << std::endl;
  }

  //Treat the various node types differently:
  if(nodeText)
  {
    conxs_print_indentation(indentation);
    std::cout << "text = \"" << nodeText->get_content() << "\"" << std::endl;
  }
  else if(nodeComment)
  {
    conxs_print_indentation(indentation);
    std::cout << "comment = " << nodeComment->get_content() << std::endl;
  }
  else if(nodeContent)
  {
    conxs_print_indentation(indentation);
    std::cout << "content = " << nodeContent->get_content() << std::endl;
  }
  else if(const xmlpp::Element* nodeElement = dynamic_cast<const xmlpp::Element*>(node))
  {
   
    //A normal Element node:
    //line() works only for ElementNodes.
    conxs_print_indentation(indentation);
    std::cout << "     line = " << node->get_line() << std::endl;

    //Print attributes:
    const xmlpp::Element::AttributeList& attributes = nodeElement->get_attributes();
   
    //The XMLConxsParer is used both for the System and SubAppType XML files.
    //To collect System function blocks we set a boolean flag when the System XML file is pasred
    //The boolean flag is set back to false and the end of the end of parsing for this XML fil
    for(xmlpp::Element::AttributeList::const_iterator iter = attributes.begin(); iter != attributes.end(); ++iter)
    {
      const xmlpp::Attribute* attribute = *iter;
      conxs_print_indentation(indentation);
      //std::cout << "  Attribute " << attribute->get_name() << " = " << attribute->get_value() << std::endl;

      if(nodename == "System")
      {
         
        conxs.setSystemOrSubApp("System");

        std::cout << "  Attribute " << attribute->get_name() << " = "
                  << attribute->get_value() << std::endl;

        if(attribute->get_name().compare("Comment") == 0)
        {
          conxs.setProjectComment(attribute->get_value());
        }

        if (attribute->get_name().compare("Name") == 0)
        {
          conxs.setProjectName(attribute->get_value());
        }

      }


      if(nodename == "VersionInfo")
      {
        std::cout << "  Attribute " << attribute->get_name() << " = "
                  << attribute->get_value() << std::endl;
        if(attribute->get_name().compare("Version") == 0)
        {
          conxs.setProjectVersion(attribute->get_value());
        }
        if(attribute->get_name().compare("Organization") == 0)
        {
          conxs.setProjectOrganization(attribute->get_value());
        }
        if(attribute->get_name().compare("Author") == 0)
        {
          conxs.setProjectAuthor(attribute->get_value());
        }
        if(attribute->get_name().compare("Date") == 0)
        {
          conxs.setProjectDate(attribute->get_value());
        }

      }

      if(nodename == "SubApp")
      {
    
        std::cout << "  Attribute " << attribute->get_name() << " = "
                    << attribute->get_value() << std::endl;
        if(attribute->get_name().compare("Comment") == 0)
        {
          conxs.setSubAppTrackerComment(attribute->get_value());
        }
        else if (attribute->get_name().compare("Name") == 0)
        {
          conxs.setSubAppTrackerName(attribute->get_value());
        }
        else if (attribute->get_name().compare("Type") == 0)
        {
          if(conxs.getSystemOrSubApp() == "System")
          {
            conxs.setSubAppTrackerType(attribute->get_value());
            conxs.addSysSubAppToSysSubAppTrackerVec();
            //conxs.addSysSubAppToSysSubAppTrackerMap();

          }
          /*
          else
          {
            //These are the nested subApps
            conxs.setSubAppTrackerType(type);
            conxs.addSubAppsInTheOrderCollected(type);
            conxs.addSubAppToSubAppTrackerVec();
          }
          */
        }
      }
     
    }
   
    const xmlpp::Attribute* attribute = nodeElement->get_attribute("title");
    if(attribute)
    {
      std::cout << "title found: =" << attribute->get_value() << std::endl;

    }
  }

  if(!nodeContent)
  {
    //Recurses through child nodes:
    xmlpp::Node::NodeList list = node->get_children();
    for(xmlpp::Node::NodeList::iterator iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
    {
      print_node(*iter, conxs, indentation + 2); //recursive
    }
  }
 
}

void runConxsParser(CONXS &conxs, std::string filepath, int indentation)
{
    try
    {
      xmlpp::DomParser parser;
      //parser.set_validate();
      parser.set_substitute_entities(); //We just want the text to be resolved/unescaped automatically.

      parser.parse_file(filepath);
     
      if(parser)
      {
        //Walk the tree:
        const xmlpp::Node* pNode = parser.get_document()->ge
t_root_node(); //deleted by DomParser.
 
        print_node(pNode, conxs);
        conxs.projectInfo();
        conxs.displayOrderedSystemLevelSubAppVec();

        /*
        if(conxs.getSystemOrSubApp() == "System")
        {
          cout << "conxs.getSystemOrSubApp()" << conxs.getSystemOrSubApp() << endl;
          conxs.collectSystemFBs();
          conxs.displaySystemFBs();
        }
        */

      }
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
      std::cout << "Exception caught: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**The functions are defined in the following code. I'm leaving out additional include files that hold structs I use as templates in vectors and maps.**

```
#include "conxs_tracker.h"
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "debug.h"

using namespace std;

CONXS::CONXS ()
{
    cout << "in CONXS constructor" << endl;
}


bool CONXS::firstCharUpper(const string &word)
{
    return word.size() && isupper(word[0]);
}


struct ProjectInfo prjInfo;

void CONXS::setProjectComment(string comment)
{
    prjInfo.comment =  comment;
}
void CONXS::setProjectName(string name)
{
    if(firstCharUpper(name))
        boost::to_lower(name);
    prjInfo.name = name;
}
void CONXS::setProjectVersion(string version)
{
    prjInfo.version = version;
}
void CONXS::setProjectOrganization(string organization)
{
    prjInfo.organization = organization;
}
void CONXS::setProjectAuthor(string author)
{
    prjInfo.author = author;
}
void CONXS::setProjectDate(string date)
{
    prjInfo.date = date;
}

void CONXS::projectInfo()
{
    cout << "prjInfo.comment " << prjInfo.comment << endl;
    cout << "prjInfo.name " << prjInfo.name << endl;
    cout << "prjInfo.version " << prjInfo.version << endl;
    cout << "prjInfo.organization " << prjInfo.organization << endl;
    cout << "prjInfo.author " << prjInfo.author << endl;
    cout << "prjInfo.date " << prjInfo.date << endl;
}

//setSystemOrSubApp is set to "System" when the system file is being parsed
//And SubAppType when a "*.sub" XML file is being parsed

void CONXS::setSystemOrSubApp(string systemOrSubApp)
{
    sysOrSubApp = systemOrSubApp;
}
string CONXS::getSystemOrSubApp()
{
    return sysOrSubApp;
}

void CONXS::setSubAppTrackerComment(string comment)
{
    sysSubAppTracker.comment = comment;
}
void CONXS::setSubAppTrackerName(string name)
{
    if(firstCharUpper(name))
        boost::to_lower(name);
    sysSubAppTracker.name = name;
}
void CONXS::setSubAppTrackerType(string type)
{
    if(firstCharUpper(type))
        boost::to_lower(type);
    sysSubAppTracker.type = type;
}
string CONXS::getSubAppTrackerComment()
{
    return sysSubAppTracker.comment;
}
string CONXS::getSubAppTrackerName()
{
    return sysSubAppTracker.name;
}
string CONXS::getSubAppTrackerType()
{
    return sysSubAppTracker.type;
}

void CONXS::addSysSubAppToSysSubAppTrackerVec()
{
       
    sysSubAppTrackerVec.push_back(sysSubAppTracker);
    //Keep a list of system subApps in the order they are found
    //orderdSysSubAppTrackerVec.push_back(sysSubAppTracker);
}

void CONXS::displayOrderedSystemLevelSubAppVec()
{
    cout << "\n#### System Level SubApps as ordered Vec ####" << endl;

    for ( vector<SubAppTracker>::iterator
                itr = sysSubAppTrackerVec.begin(), end = sysSubAppTrackerVec.end();
                itr != end;  ++itr )
    {
        cout << "Comment: " << itr->comment << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << itr->name << endl;
        cout << "Type: " << itr->type << endl;
        cout << endl; 
    }      
}
```

And here is my automake file

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4 --install

bin_PROGRAMS = xerlangCPL
xerlangCPL_SOURCES = \
    src/xmlPROC.cpp \
    src/xml_structs.h \
    src/debug.h \
    src/conxsTracker.cpp \
    src/conxs_tracker.h \
    src/xmlConxsParser.cpp \
    src/oven_control


xerlangCPL_LDFLAGS = -DDEBUG \
                     $(libxml_LIBS) \
                     $(BOOST_LDFLAGS) \
                     $(BOOST_SYSTEM_LDFLAGS) \
                     $(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LDFLAGS) \
                     $(BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LDFLAGS)

xerlangCPL_CPPFLAGS = $(libxml_CFLAGS) \
                      $(BOOST_CPPFLAGS)
                     

xerlangCPL_LIBS = $(BOOST_SYSTEM_LIBS) \
                  $(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIBS) \
                  $(BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBS)

xerlangCPL_CXXFLAGS = -lboost_filesystem -ldl -lboost_system

# start of Doxygen section
if HAVE_DOXYGEN

doxyfile.stamp:
    $(DOXYGEN) $(top_srcdir)/doc/Doxyfile
    echo Timestamp > $@


CLEANFILES = $(top_srcdir)/doxyfile.stamp

# all-local: doxyfile.stamp
all-local: doxyfile.stamp
# clean-local:
#     rm -rf $(top_srcdir)/
endif

EXTRA_DIST = bootstrap m4/NOTES
```

When I do a `make` using the Automake-based makefile, I get the following error:

> ```
> src/xmlConxsParser.cpp:41:42: error: ‘CONXS’ has not been declared
>  void print_node(const xmlpp::Node* node, CONXS &conxs, unsigned int indentation = 0)
>                                           ^~~~~
> src/xmlConxsParser.cpp: In function ‘void print_node(const xmlpp::Node*, int&, unsigned int)’:
> src/xmlConxsParser.cpp:109:15: error: request for member ‘setSystemOrSubApp’ in ‘conxs’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
>          conxs.setSystemOrSubApp("System")
> ```

**So as you can see automake does not see the overloaded function. Would you know what i should do to, to make this work?**

Comment: Automake neither sees nor fails to see your overloaded function.  That's a behavior of the compiler.  I am inclined to guess that there is another, more fundamental error reported earlier in the build output: the compiler failing to find one or more of your headers.  That could indeed result from a flaw in your autotooling, but I cannot verify that specifically because you do not seem to have presented a [mre].

Comment: However, there are some definite points of concern both in your source and in your `Makefile.am`.  Among them: as a matter of style, one should not `#include` one .cpp file into another.  If a file contains code meant to be included into a larger translation unit then it should be named and structured as a header.

Comment: Also, link libraries for a program should be listed in that program's `_LDADD` variable, not among its `_CXXFLAGS`, nor via a `_LIBS` variable (which means something quite different).  It is also suspicious, but not necessarily wrong, to see `$(libxml_CFLAGS)` included into the preprocessor flags (`xerlangCPL_CPPFLAGS`).  Depending on the meaning and contents of that variable it might need to be included instead or additionally in the C++ compiler flags (`xerlangCPL_CXXFLAGS`).

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Bollinger, I edited the Makefile.am  to read as follows xerlangCPL_LDFLAGS = -DDEBUG \
      $(libxml_LIBS) \
      $(BOOST_LDFLAGS) \
      $(BOOST_SYSTEM_LDFLAGS) \
      $(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LDFLAGS) \
      $(BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LDFLAGS)

xerlangCPL_CPPFLAGS = $(BOOST_CPPFLAGS)
      

xerlangCPL_LDADD = $(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIB) \
       $(BOOST_LD_LIB) \
       $(BOOST_SYSTEM_LIB)

xerlangCPL_CXXFLAGS = $(libxml_CFLAGS)